# Нужно ли избавляться от Кракозябр в phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, кодировка, веб-программирование, mysql

Я везде задал кодировку utf8. И на сайте у меня русские буквы(полученные из БД) отображаются нормально(т.е. если я отправлю строку русского текста в б.д., а потом прочитаю её от туда и впихну в html страничку, то она отобразиться нормально.). Но когда я открываю базу в phpMyAdmin, то там вместо русских букв кракозябры...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нормально ли это, и стоит ли в этим бороться? Т.е. могут ли из-за этого например возникнуть сложности с сортировкой или ещё чем нибудь таким?

Answer (score 1):

Выставьте в настройках mysql кодировку utf8 и будет вам счастье

Comment: @MDJHD, а как у MySQL сервера установить кодировку, когда он поставляется вместе с хочтингом?

Comment: Нужно что-бы кодировка везде совпадала и на сайте и в ПХПМАЙАДМИНЕ, можете попробовать перекодировать таблицы, как рекоммендуют например здесь -> http://forum.php-myadmin.ru/viewtopic.php?id=2766 , перед отправкой данных в БД явно указывайте, в какой кодировке вы их отправляете

     $mysqli->query("SET CHARSET utf8"